# Python pandas merge condicional

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy haciendo un merge de dos dataframe que tienen 3 campos comunes.  El tema es que si no encuentra el valor buscado debería buscar otro que coincidieran 2 de los campos o sólo 1 y no sé hacerlo en pandas.

En la situación perfecta debería encontrar los 3 campos comunes en los 2 dataframes:

```
'OFICINA_A' 'INC_A' 'N____A' -> 'OFICINA_B' 'INC_B' 'N____B'
```

Si no encuentra debería encontrar coincidencias sólo con donde:

```
 'INC_A' 'N____A' ->  'INC_B' 'N____B'
```

o:

```
 'OFICINA_A' 'N____A' -> 'OFICINA_B' 'N____B'
```

Mi código actual es:

```
df_query = pd.merge(df_dip, df_2, how='left', left_on=['Oficina_a', 'Incidencia_a', 'Codigo_a'], right_on=['Oficina_b', 'Incidencia_b', 'Codigo_b'])
```

He probado con:

```
df_query = pd.merge(df_dip, df_2, how='left', (left_on=['Oficina_a', 'Incidencia_a', 'Codigo_a'], right_on=['Oficina_b', 'Incidencia_b', 'Codigo_b']) | (left_on=['Incidencia_a', 'Codigo_a'], right_on=['Incidencia_b', 'Codigo_b']))
```

Pero no lo admite.

¿Cómo tengo que modificara el merge para que contemple las diferentes opciones?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola! Desconozco si existe forma de hacerlo con una doble condicional dentro de merge. Pero con un `for`si es posible, no se si te interesa la respuesta de esa manera. Saludos!

Comment: Hola. Hasta donde yo sé, no se puede hacer "merge" con condiciones. "on", "left_on" y "right_on" aceptan el nombre de una columna o una lista con nombres de columnas, pero no condiciones. De todas formas, ¿no se obtendría el mismo resultado haciendo sólo 1 merge a partir de 1 sóla columna (el caso menos restrictivo)?